# Unable to access the file from the object URL

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I am unable to access the file, that I am trying to access through pre-signed URL.

```
    $cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
            'Bucket' => 'test-bucket-pcloud',
            'Key'    => 'testfile.txt'
    ]);

    $request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');

    // Get the actual presigned-url
    $presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
```

When the URL is accessed on browser I get:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
    <Error>
    <Code>AuthorizationQueryParametersError</Code>
    <Message>X-Amz-Algorithm only supports "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"</Message>
    <RequestId>8D109D39C69E665D</RequestId>
    <HostId>
    lH+u+MEnbF+Sps0kd/tMEGS0ePHjQlUDGWN8lLnzkXYkrIb0YksK6ahzUflPFMbQG8zUzLFl9y4=
    </HostId>
    </Error>
```

What could be the reason for it? Also, when I try to access the bucket from the URL obtained as:

```
$signedURL = $s3Client->getObjectUrl('test-bucket-pcloud','testfile.txt');
```

I still get the same error.

Here is the permission snapshot for the bucket:

[image]

Comment: Looks like your client doesn't support the necessary encryption algorithms.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Sorry but what does that mean?

Comment: I have no experience with AWS, so this is just a guess. But the server is complainging that your client doesn't support `AWS4-HMAC-SHA256`, which is an amazon variation of a common part in encryption algorithms. Either your client doesn't support it (maybe it is outdated), or it is configured wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check you CORS Configuration?

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

In a common CORS Configuration, you can allow origin, method and header. I'll start by adding a CORS Configuration.